# Reduction from SAT to 3SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, reductions

a few days ago I had a test and could not pass it. This is a question I did not understand in the test.

> Recall the reduction we saw $SAT \leq _p 3SAT$. Given verse $\varphi$ in the form of $CNF$, we converted each fragment $C_i$ in $\varphi$ to verse $D_i$ in the form of $CNF$ by adding new variables. Then, we returned:

$f(\varphi )= \wedge _{i=1}^{m}D_i$, for m is the number of verses in $\varphi$.

Let there be some verse $\varphi= C_1\wedge C_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge C_m$.

> Find a bound on the number of verses in $f(\varphi)$:
>
> 1. Between $m$ and $m^2$
> 2. Between $2m$ and $m^2$
> 3. If we denote by $h$ the amount of variables in the longest verse in $\varphi$ then: $(h-2)\cdot m$.
> 4. This cannot be determined because we do not know the size of each verse $C_i$
> 5. None of the above claims are true.

I can not find the answer. I can not find a relationship between m and h and the size of the number of verses

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed it, instead of block I meant bound / barrier

Comment: Do you allow clauses with less than $3$ literals to be in 3-SAT?

Comment: No, it should be in exactly clauses with 3 literals

Comment: Do you allow repeated literals?

Comment: Yes, Literal can appear several times in clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question refers to a specific transformation that you have seen during the course but we are not given, so we can only guess.

A standard transformation from a SAT clause $C$ to a collection of 3-SAT clauses is as follows:

- If $C$ already contains $3$ literals, then $C$ is left unchanged.
- If $C$ contains $1$ (resp. $2$) literals, then add $2$ (resp. $1$) copies of a literal from $C$ to $C$ itself.
- If $C$ contains $k \ge 4$ literals, then let $C = \ell_1 \vee \ell_2 \vee \dots \vee \ell_k$. Add $k-3$ new variables $x_3, \dots, x_{k-1}$ andeplace $C$ with:
  $$
  (\ell_1 \vee \ell_2 \vee x_3) \wedge \left( \bigwedge_{i=3}^{k-2}(\overline{x}_i \vee \ell_i \vee x_{i+1}) \right) \wedge (\overline{x}_{k-1}, \ell_{k-1}, \ell_k)
  $$

Notice how the above subformula contains 2 original literals in the first and in the last clauses, and 1 original literal in each of the intermediate clauses. Therefore the overall number of 3-SAT clauses needed to represent $C$ is $2 + (k-4) = k-2$.

This shows you that option 3 is correct.

Regarding the other options:

- 1 Is incorrect. Think of a formula with a single clause with $4$ variables.
- 2 Is incorrect. Think of a SAT formula that is also already a 3-SAT formula.
- Regarding 4, we can certainly find upper and lower bounds. In fact we can even find the exact number of clauses. If there are $m$ clauses and the number of variables in the $i$-th clause is $m_i$ then the final number of clauses will be $\sum_{i=1}^m \max\{m_i-2, 1\}$.
- 5 is false since 3 is true.

Comment: If we have 9 clauses of 6 variables and one clause of a single variable. We'll need 31 clauses, while the option 3 suggests 30, am I right?

Comment: To transform each of the 9 clauses of 6 variables you need $4$ 3-SAT clauses, for a total of $9 \cdot 4 = 36$ clauses. We only need 1 3-SAT clause to encode the clause with a single variable. Overall we need $36+1 = 37$ clauses. Option 3 says we need [at most, i presume]  $(h-2) \cdot 10 = (6-2) \cdot 10 = 4 \cdot 10 = 40$ clauses.